# Implementing a WebServer

Tags: http, networking, language-agnostic, webserver

I am trying to create a Web Server of my own and there are several questions about working of Web servers we are using today. Questions are:

1. After receiving a HTTP request from a client through port 80, does server respond using same port 80?
2. If yes then while sending a large file say a pic in MB's, webserver will be unable to receive requests from other clients?
3. Is a computer port duplex or simplex? (Can it send and receive at the same time)?
4. If another port on server side is used to send response to client, then (if TCP is used, which is generally used), again 3-way handshaking will be done which will be overhead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html here is a good guide on what's going on with webservers, although it's in c but the concepts are all there. This will explain the whole client server relationship as well as some implementation details.

I'll just give a high level on what's going on:
Usually what happens is when your server gets a new request that comes in it creates a fork that will process it, that way you are not bogged down by each request, when the request comes in the child process is handed a new file to write to(again this is all implementation details).

So really you have one server waiting for requests and for each request it received it spawns a child to process to deal with this request. I'm sure there are much easier languages to implement this stuff than c(I had to do both a c and java server serving to either one in my past) but c really gets you to understand the things that are going on and I'm betting that is what you are looking for here

Now there are a couple of things to think about:
how you want the webserver to work. The example explains the parent child process.
Do you want to use tcp/UDP there are differences in the way to payload gets delivered.
You don't have to connect on port 80. that's just the default for web.

Hopefully the guide will help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. The server sends the response using the TCP connection established by the client, so it also responds using the same port. The server can handle connections from multiple clients using the same port because TCP connections are identified by (local-ip, local-port, remote-ip, remote-port), so the server can even handle multiple connections from same client provided that the source ports are different.
2. There are different techniques you can use to be able to serve multiple clients at the same time. These include

   - using multiple processes or threads: when one is busy serving a client the others can serve other clients.
   - using events: the server listens for events from the OS: when it can write a block of data to a connection it writes it, when a new client connects it accepts the connection, ...

   Frequently both approaches are be combined.
3. A TCP connection is duplex: you can send and receive at the same time. The HTTP protocol is based on a simple request-response model though: at any given time only one party is "talking."

Comment: My focus is on the server side port. Can that port send a response to a client and simultaneously listen for new client requests? If yes then programmatically how? If no then what technique is used to avoid such situation in which server has to send large files (say image file) and simultaneously be readily available for incoming client requests...

Comment: Yes, it can, and the way this is done in all socket APIs is that the socket used to accept connections is separate from the sockets used for communicating with clients. I recommend you find a tutorial on network programming for your favorite programming language on your favorite operating system as it will explain all of this...

Comment: Can you please implement this line on c or Java code: "socket used to accept connections is separate from the sockets used for communicating with clients." ?.
Because when I am looking in any tutorial in Java, way it is done (as they say) is 
 ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789); 
      while(true) { 
      
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();

Now here If I monitor my network activity through tcpdump or netstat or list open ports from nmap, etc. It doesn't show me any other port (other than onServer is listening) is used to send data to client.

Comment: As you can see, you have a `ServerSocket` for the listening socket, and a plain `Socket` for the client that connected. If you list the open network connections you should see that you have a socket in `LISTEN` state on port 80, corresponding to the `ServerSocket`, and a different socket for each connection, in other states. You will see that the local port of each connection is 80, since that's the port the server uses, but the remote addresses (IP, port) will be distinct.

Comment: That's the problem. On server side when I monitor network connections, it shows all the activities done with different clients through its standard port no 80. (In my code above, port no is 6789). I have tested it with tcpdump, monitoring each packet carefully. In simple words as per above code -"It doesn't create separate local ports on server to interact with received client requests". 
Question-Then how implementation is done in actual web servers.?

Comment: If you are looking at output from `netstat` pay attention to the "foreign address" column, you will see different addresses...